# Readers delight,does it need any tweaks?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan, food, recipe-request

I'm writing a recipe called [Readers Delight!](https://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/readers-delight-412781) which I have shared on Genius Kitchen (*previously Food.com*). My goal is for the recipe to have one ingredient for every letter in the alphabet. This is the recipe so far:

- 1 (24 ounce) can alphabet pasta
- 1⁄2 cup orange juice
- 3 large carrots
- 1 avocado, pulp
- 1⁄3 cup wheat germ
- 4 cups croutons
- 3 teaspoons sesame seeds
- 1 pinch salt and pepper
- 1⁄3 cup red pepper flakes
- 1 yellow banana

DIRECTIONS

- Pour soup & orange juice into a medium pot.
- Add all ingredients except croutons.
- Cook over medium heat for 45 minutes.
- Add croutons toward the end of the cooking process.
- Serve warm or chilled.

Now my question is this: after viewing this recipe, does it need any tweaking to be vegan-friendly? If so what tweaks would you recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the ingredients you've listed are unprocessed vegetables, fruits, or seasonings all of which are already vegan. There are only two ingredients which might raise concern: pasta and croutons.

*Pasta* is usually purchased in one of three ways.

- Dry pasta in a box is almost always vegan, with only basic ingredients like semolina and wheat flour. This dry [Catelli alphabet pasta](https://www.catelli.ca/en/product/alphabets/) is vegan.
- Fresh pasta (not dry) might not be vegan, because it is often prepared with egg.
- Canned pasta might not be vegan because dairy products are common in the sauce, such as with this can of [Alpha-getti](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/heinz-alpha-getti-alphabet-pasta-with-tomato-sauce/6000016940566).

*Croutons* are commonly made by brushing slices of bread with butter (a dairy product). Many pre-packaged croutons available in stores are not vegan, so either read labels carefully or make your own.

To make sure this recipe is vegan, I suggest the following tweaks:

- Recommend dry alphabet pasta specifically, or leave it up to the reader to find some canned alphabet pasta that is vegan.
- Link to a recipe for vegan homemade croutons, like [this one](https://ohsheglows.com/2010/10/22/easy-homemade-croutons/) from Oh She Glows.